# How to redirect after login in PHP

Tags: php

I have a simple website trying to figure out how to redirect to home.php after login at the moment it just stays in the login page.

```
    <?php
  session_start();



  if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: login.php');
  }
  if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    header("location: login.php");
  }
?>
```

Comment: What is the login page? Please show the login page

Comment: You don't have any code redirect to home. You have code to redirect to login...perhaps you can copy that and change it, and add a redirect to home - in suitable circumstances (which you didn't specify).

Answer (score 1):

Add to login.php:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header("Location: /home.php");
}
```